# Copy title data in new column and format it

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy

[image: Example]

The script I need should read the date in column B and copy it to column D with european date format and should sort column D (newest date first, oldest last) 
It should be able to handle more than one row added at once ..

(No, sadly I cant change the way the spreadsheet gets input)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming John (08/08/2017) is in B2, put this in B2:

```
=substitute(substitute(index(split(B2," "),0,2),"(",""),")","")
```

If you don't want script.

Comment: @Rubén Sorry, I misread it. I corrected the column and will just leave it if that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

## Code

```
/**
 * Extracts the date of the active cell and use it to set the value
 * of the cell to columns to the right
 * @example active cell value "John (08/08/2017)"
 * //returns 08/08/2017
 */
function myFunction() {
  var origin = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var rowOffset = 0;
  var columnOffset = 2;
  var destination = origin.offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)
  var value = /\((.*?)\)/.exec(origin.getValue())[1];
  destination.setValue(value)
}
```

## Reference

- [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Comment: if i want to run the script for all rows, what do i have to change?

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details in order to know what do you mean by all rows (the selected rows, the rows of the data range, ...)

Comment: hope its understandable now :/